# Watch, apply same code to 2 different functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I don't know if the title is the best to describe my problem, but was the best way to introduce my daubt.

So basically i have this:

```
 watch: {
        valueYou: function(val){
            if(val < 15){
                this.progressYou.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            else if(val < 50){
                this.progressYou.backgroundColor = "orange";
            }
            else{
                this.progressYou.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
        },
        valueMonster: function(val){
             if(val < 15){
                this.progressMonster.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            else if(val < 50){
                this.progressMonster.backgroundColor = "orange";
            }
            else{
                this.progressMonster.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
        }
    }
```

as you can see, there are just 1 think that changes, that is the this.progressMonster and this.progressYou, i really want to optimize this into a function and really need to know how to that, how can i pass trough a function the name of the data variable that i wanna apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that turns the value into the color:

```
function progressColor(p) {
  if (p < 15) return "red";
  if (p < 50) return "orange";
  return "green";
}
```

Now call that in your object:

```
watch: {
  valueYou: function (val) {
    this.progressYou.backgroundColor = progressColor(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome solution, sometimes i don't figure out how to transform my solutionin something like that :/ need more practice, thanks friend :D

Comment: The next step would be to turn it into a `computed`.

Comment: i am a little confused with computed and methods, i know computed is used to output and methods to do things and that computer just renders the specific part and methods all the page, but when exactly should i use 1 and other?

Comment: A `method` in general is used to do something. The `computed` object is useful when you want to output data but not 1:1 but slightly changed. The idea is that whenever you change a variable, its computed properties are updated _automatically_, while a method has to be called by you. I'm actually not sure if `computed` is of much value here, given that you're already using `watch`. Then again, I have no clue about vue, I just read the part of the docs about `computed` five seconds ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
methods:{
    setBackground: function(val, element){
        if(val < 15){
            element.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        else if(val < 50){
            element.backgroundColor = "orange";
        }
        else{
            element.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
},
watch: {
    valueYou: function(val){
        this.setBackground(val, this.progressYou);
    },
    valueMonster: function(val){
        this.setBackground(val, this.progressMonster);
    }
}
```